# Accessing Firebase unique ID from within ngFor using AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire2 to get a list of data from Firebase. Here is my code:

```
  private _tasksList = this._af.list('tasks');
  tasks: any[];

  constructor(private _af: AngularFireDatabase){}

  ngOnInit(){
     this._tasksList
         .valueChanges()
         .subscribe((tasks)=> {
            this.tasks = tasks;
     });
  }
```

I'm using this **tasks array** to iterate and show the data using ***ngFor**. I want to pass the unique ID that is generated by Firebase on Pushing data to my **onEditTask** and **onDeleteTask** function in order to edit or delete the tasks.

```
  <div *ngFor="let task of tasks; let id = index" >
    <div class="card-header">
      {{task.type}}
      <span class="pull-right">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil" (click)="onEditTask(id)"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-trash" (click)="onDeleteTask(id)"></i>
          </span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">{{task.title}}</h4>
      <p class="card-text">{{task.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Is there any way I can get that in this scenario?

Here is How [My Tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iXse.png) looks like.

Comment: use `.snapshotChanges()` instead of `.valueChanges()` check this [example app](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#deleting-the-entire-list)

Comment: That worked, Thanks for the suggestion bro.